# Mongodb - aggregate - Get records from a set of records for each date from a set of dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

==Edit==

Initial records from DB:

```
[{ _id: 100,
  ca : 12,
  st : 0,
 tranhisRev: [
 { 
   uid : 1,
   et: 2018-02-08T11:28:53.745Z },
 { 
   uid : 2,
   et: 2018-02-08T11:28:55.745Z },
 { 
   uid : 3,
   et: 2018-02-07T10:56:05.993Z },
 {
   uid : 4,
   et: 2018-02-07T10:56:08.927Z },
 { 
   uid : 1,
   et: 2018-02-06T10:55:57.094Z },
 { 
   uid : 2,
   et: 2018-02-06T10:59:57.094Z }
]},
{ _id: 101,
  ca : 19,
  st : 1,
 tranhisRev: [
 { 
   uid : 1,
   et: 2018-02-08T11:28:53.745Z },
 { 
   uid : 2,
   et: 2018-02-08T11:28:55.745Z },
 { 
   uid : 3,
   et: 2018-02-07T10:56:05.993Z },
 {
   uid : 4,
   et: 2018-02-07T10:56:08.927Z },
 { 
   uid : 1,
   et: 2018-02-06T10:55:57.094Z },
 { 
   uid : 2,
   et: 2018-02-06T10:59:57.094Z }
]}
]
```

I want to get the last records for each date i.e. 6th feb, 7th feb and 8th feb and for each '_id'.

Desired result is :

```
[
{ _id: 100,
  ca : 12,
  st : 0,
 tranhisRev: 
 { 
   uid : 1,
   et: 2018-02-08T11:28:55.745Z } },

{ _id: 100,
  ca : 12,
  st : 0,
tranhisRev: 
 {
   uid : 4,
   et: 2018-02-07T10:56:08.927Z } },

{ _id: 100,
  ca : 12,
  st : 0,
tranhisRev: 
 { 
   uid : 2,
   et: 2018-02-06T10:59:57.094Z} },

{ _id: 101,
  ca : 19,
  st : 1,
 tranhisRev: 
 { 
   uid : 2,
   et: 2018-02-08T11:28:55.745Z } },

{ _id: 101,
  ca : 19,
  st : 1,
tranhisRev: 
 {
   et: 2018-02-07T10:56:05.927Z } },

{ _id: 101,
  ca : 19,
  st : 1,
tranhisRev: 
 { 
   uid : 2,
   et: 2018-02-06T10:59:57.094Z } }]
```

I have tried to use

```
$group:
{
    _id: "$_id",
    tranhisRev: {$first: "$tranhisRev"}
}
```

But did not help me and I got one record for each `_id`.

`$redact` I have tried using but that also did not help me.

`$redact` will help if for only one day I want to get data. But the problem is I have to get records for multiple dates as well.

Can someone guide me on how I can achieve this?

Any existing question link also will help.

Comment: how you managed to insert non-unique _id?

Comment: Try `db.collection.aggregate({$sort:{"et":-1}}, 
 {"$group":{
  "_id":{
    "$dateToString":{"format":"%Y-%m-%d","date":"$et"}
  },
  "first":{
    "$first":"$$ROOT"
  }
}}])`

Comment: @AlexBlex These records I got after using $unwind on 2 records. tranhis is an array field in each record.

Comment: @Veeram your query is not helping me to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

*"For each day for each id"* means you need to group by both values, i.e. include both day and _id in the grouping _id:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$tranhisRev" },
    { $group: { 
        _id: { 
            id: "$_id", 
            day: { $dateToString: { format:"%Y-%m-%d", date:"$tranhisRev.et" } }
        }, 
        et:{ $max:"$tranhisRev.et" } 
    } }
])
```

Comment: This query did not give me the desired output I have mentioned in the question. I have some fields in `tranhisRev ` array along with `et` that also I want to get along with et. Is it possible?

Comment: @Shrabanee Everything is possible if you stop changing the question. I answer the question "I have tried .... But I got one record for each _id"  with explanation why your approach is not working and how to fix it. I do not give you the copy-and-paste solution to use in production code directly.  Be creative, read, learn, and apply the knowledge to your usecase.

Comment: I don't want to copy paste any code either. I am trying to get it done myself instead of waiting for some answer to copy paste. Since I am not so used to aggregation I am trying to get some help here.

Comment: @Shrabanee So since you learned how to group  "for each day for each id" instead of "one record for each _id"  from myself and how to use `$sort` from Veeram, you can apply this pieces of wisdom to **your** pipeline and format the result to match the "desired output".

Comment: I will try. Thanks